# mvc retrieve many data in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp.net MVC application which can retrieve data from database. It looks like this:

If my url is like this:

```
myurl.com/Home/Index/1
```

my view is like this: [https:// scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/t31.0-8/10571949_782177481813619_1929089026797570629_o.jpg][1]

if url is like this :-

```
myurl.com/Home/Index/2
```

view is like this: https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/10519689_782177478480286_8967524557745769669_o.jpg

etc..

I'm passing and in url which is the id of data in my database :-

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        BIOEntities db = new BIOEntities();
        AddBio bio = new AddBio();
        Biography biography = db.Biographies.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        bio.Id = biography.Id;
        bio.Photo = biography.Photo;
        bio.Name = biography.Name;
        bio.Position = biography.Position;

        return View(bio);
    }
```

Now i want to make that if my url will

```
myurl.com/Home/Index
```

It must retrieve data like this: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/10454247_782178191813548_1334099737795866885_o.jpg

anyone please explain me how can I do that

```
[1]: https://%20scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/t31.0-8/10571949_782177481813619_1929089026797570629_o.jpg
```

and there's my view (Customhelper is for pictures..) :

```
 @model BioMVC.Models.AddBio

 @using BioMVC.CustomHtmlHelpers

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="first">
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.Image(@Model.Photo, new { @id = "FirstPhoto" })
    </div>
    <legend class="orangeText">@Model.Name</legend>
    <legend class="orangeText">@Model.Position</legend>
    </div>

<div id="second">
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.Image(@Model.Photo, new { @id = "secondPhoto" })
    </div>
    <legend class="orangeText">@Model.Name</legend>
    <legend class="orangeText">@Model.Position</legend>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.Image(@Model.Photo, new { @id = "thirdPhoto" })
    </div>
    <legend class="orangeText">@Model.Name</legend>
    <legend class="orangeText">@Model.Position</legend>
</div>

<div id="fourth">
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.Image(@Model.Photo, new { @id = "fourthPhoto" })
    </div>
    <legend class="orangeText">@Model.Name</legend>
    <legend class="orangeText">@Model.Position</legend>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

george,

without seeing your current view code, i am assuming that it is something along the lines of:

```
@model yournamespace.models.AddBio
```

this will therefore only show a SINGLE instance as per the code in the current index action method. What you need to do is to make that model a `List<AddBio>` along the lines of:

```
@model List<yournamespace.models.AddBio>
```

you can then iterate round the list to populate as you had been before. You will also need to change your index method to reference a List<>, rather than a single entity (hint: removing the `.FirstOrDefault()` on the 3rd line is your starting point - the rest is all just common sense in passing back the List<> rather than a single instance).

hope this helps..

**[edit]** - as per stephen muecke's response, you should also test for nullable id -good point!!

Comment: hi jim, 
thanks for answer. I have added my view in question. please see it